# Is there any callback for swipe back gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Sometimes when user go back to the previous `UIViewController`, I want to do something.

If the user clicked the back button in `UINavigationBar`, I can capture the event.

But if they use the swipe back gesture to go back, I cannot respond to the change.

So is there any callback for swipe back gesture?

Currently I can only disable this kind of page in my app through

```
interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: Does viewWillDissapear / viewDidDisappear not do what you want?

Comment: @Tander There are other actions like push new `UIViewController` that will cause `viewWillDisappear`. I just want to hook the back action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to hook into the one that's already built into `UINavigationController` by doing something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleBackswipe))
}
    
@objc private func handleBackswipe() {
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleBackswipe))
    // insert your custom code here
}
```

The remember to call `removeTarget(_:action:)` in your selector, otherwise it'll spam your selector until the gesture ends.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.It gives you some what better solution.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer*)[self.navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0];
        [gesture addTarget:self action:@selector(moved:)];
}
```

In Target method.

```
-(void)moved:(id)sender{    
    // do what you want

//finally remove the target
    [[self.navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0] removeTarget:self action:@selector(moved:)];
}
```